# How to stop execution of a function via add_action hook?

Tags: hooks, actions

I have the following functions:

```
function test($post_id){

do_action('test_action',$post_id);

echo $post_id;

}

add_action('test_action',function($post_id){

if ( $post_id == 2 ) //Stop test function execution

}
```

Using the function hooked to `add_action`, how to stop the execution of `test()` function without adding any code to `test()`. In the above example, if `$post_id == 2` , the `echo $post_id;` code should not run in `test()`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me, but if you want to stop code from executing in a function as a certain point, you can add `return`, or you can wrap the code in a conditional

Comment: I meant that using `add_action` hook, how to stop the execution of `test()` function with contains `do_action`. In the above example, if `$post_id == 2` , the `echo $post_id;` code should not run in `test()`

Comment: You can’t. You can use `exit` but that would stop absolutely everything else from continuing.

Answer (score -1):

The usual way to add an action hook is more like this:

```
// ... some other code
do_action( 'my_action', $post_id );

// ...elsewhere
add_action( 'my_action', 'wpse405965_function' );
/**
 * Function hooked to my_action
 *
 * @param int $post_id The post ID.
 */
function wpse405965_function( $post_id ) {
    if ( 2 !== $post_id ) {
        echo $post_id;
    }
}
```

The way you've wrapped the `do_action()` inside a function confuses me. It seems extraneous.

### Reference

- [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/)

Answer (score -1):

You have both registered and called action hooks, did you know you could do the same with filters? This answer uses a filter to call a `return;` statement as the community suggested, to do an early return and stop executing the rest of `test` function body (echo in your case).

```php
function test($post_id)
{
    do_action('test_action', $post_id);

    if ( apply_filters('wpse_405965_stop_execution', false) )
        return;

    echo $post_id;
}

add_action('test_action', function($post_id)
{
    if ( $post_id == 2 ) // Stop test function execution
        add_filter('wpse_405965_stop_execution', '__return_true');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, a plugin I was using had the above code and I did not want to edit the core code of the plugin, hence was trying to figure out a way to achieve this via `add_action`

Comment: Yep. That's the best way to go about customising/extending a plugin - especially when the authors were kind enough to include filters and action hooks.